# How can I add one more select option to jQuery UI combobox with remote source on client side?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/k2J5v/27/) is the code of jquery ui combobox with remote source. I need to add one more select option ('any city') to that combobox on client side (with javascript/jquery usage). How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably insert the value in the success callback when you get the data beck from the search URL. Something like this (I've trimmed out some extraneous code):

```
/* ... */
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: self.options.source,
        type: "POST",
        /* snip */
        success: function(data) {
            data.geonames.unshift({
              name: 'Any City',
              countryName: '...'
            });
            // the rest of the success callback as before...
        },
        /* snip */
    });
},
/* ... */
```

The `unshift` method of Javascript arrays inserts a value into the front of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If it should happend only one time during combobox initialisation you may use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/ on data.geonames to combine it with something like this:

```
{
  name: 'aaa',
  adminName1: 'bbbb',
  countryName: 'cccc'
}
```

that should be done right at the beginning of success callback in your $.ajax call.

Comment: This will not happen once at initialization, but each time the `$.ajax` call is issued.